# Adding millis to a date

Tags: java, scala, date

Recently I stumbled across a strange behaviour while adding some millis to a `Date`. Why does the second example produce `11:00` instead of `12:00`?

```
def addWeek(s: String) = {
  val df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm")
  val utcMillisSinceEpoch = df.parse(s).getTime
  val weekMillis = 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L * 7L
  df.format(new java.util.Date(utcMillisSinceEpoch + weekMillis))
}
addWeek("2013/10/01 12:00") // 2013/10/08 12:00
addWeek("2013/10/21 12:00") // 2013/10/28 11:00
addWeek("2013/11/21 12:00") // 2013/11/28 12:00
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, just a side note: This is not a reliable way to add a week to a date. Because of leap years and DST, weeks can have a different duration. Better use the `GregorianCalendar`, and increase the week field. If you want to have a sophisticated API, I recommend taking a look at `Joda Time`, which is the date support like it *should* be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The daylight saving time ends end of october. Therefore the second `addWeek` call shifts your date over the end of DST.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your locale, daylight savings time may end around that period. When DST ends, one hour is repeated.

It looks like you're in Germany. In that locale, DST ends Sunday, October 27.